# How to animate a child element with dynamic width content to the center of its parent div, jquery, greensock, css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate a child span to the center of its parent container regardless of the width of the span.

Below is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn btn--large ">
    <a href="">
        <span>
        NEXT CASE STUDY
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 2px solid #0c315d;
}

.btn--large a {
    padding: 16px 60px 16px 16px;
    display: block;
}

.btn span {
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
}
```

**Jquery with greensock**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // vars
    $btnSpan = $('.btn a span');

    // animate button text
    $(".btn a").bind("mouseenter",function(){
       $(this).find($btnSpan).stop(true, false).animate({left: 50% -$btnSpan.width()/1.5, ease: "Bounce",}, 600);

    }).bind("mouseleave",function(){
       $(this).find($btnSpan).stop(true, false).animate({left:"0%", ease: "Bounce"}, 200);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

**Here is a link to a jsfiddle I created**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satbulsara/nbr3rvLk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can center it by calculating the parents width and padding:

```
  var paddingLeft = parseInt($btnParent.css('paddingLeft'));
  var moveLeft = $btnParent.outerWidth()/2-$btnSpan.width()/2-paddingLeft;
  $(this).find($btnSpan).stop(true, false).animate({
        left: moveLeft, ease: "Bounce"}, 600);
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/nhnyhv1j/